# show loading percentage of loading a page

Tags: jquery, loading, percentage

I have a webpage with several images in it, and I preload them and then I fadeIn() them. I'd love to see the percentage (no bar, no image, just numbers changing) of the total images loaded.
Is that possible with jquery?

Comment: You can probably use something like .load or .on("load"):  http://api.jquery.com/load-event/ and write a jQuery function to update the progress display.

Comment: But how can you get the number that is going to change as the images load?it should go from 0% to 100%

Answer (score 2):

Definitely possible, with a variation of `.on()` :

```
var i = 0;

$('img').each(function() {

  $(this).one('load', function() {
  i++;
  console.log(i);
  });

});
```

In it's most basic form. Something similar can be done with dynamically loaded content.